# Show that $Tf$ is well-defined and is continious

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let Hilbert space $H=L^2((0,\infty),dt)$ where $dt$ is the Lebesgue measure. For each $f\in H$, define $Tf:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$
(Tf)(s)=\frac{1}{s}\int_{(0,s)}f(t)dt.
$$
**Show that $Tf$ well-defined.** What I think is, I should check if the integral converges (absolutely). Since the limit is unique in general, we must have that $Tf$ is uniquely determined, and hence it is well-defined.

**Show that $Tf$ is continuous.** I think it is easier to show that $Tf(s+\delta)\to Tf(s)$ as $\delta\to 0$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{s+\delta}\int_{(0,s+\delta)}f(t)dt=\frac{s}{s+\delta}\left ( Tf(s)+\int_{(s,s+\delta)}f(t)dt \right ).
$$
Taking $\delta \to 0$, may I use/write on the last integral to $\int_{\{s\}}f(t)dt$, which gives 0?

Comment: $T$ is well-defined because $f \in L^2$ implies $f \in L^1$ on every finite interval. And the integral does not depend on which representative element you use in the equivalence class.

Comment: For a fixed $s$, I believe they want you to show that $Tf$ is a continuous linear functional, which it is by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\in L^2\bigl((0,+\infty)\bigr)$ and $s>0$, $f|_{(0,s)}\in L^2\bigl((0,s)\bigr)$. Since $1\in L^2\bigl((0,s)\bigr)$,$$f|_{(0,s)}=f|_{(0,s)}\times1\in L^1\bigl((0,s)\bigr).$$Therefore, $T$ is well defined.

Concerning continuity, you must tell us first to which space $Tf$ belongs and which topology is being used there.

Comment: Your comment on continuity makes sense if we're trying to show $T$ is continuous. Although I wonder whether the OP got the problem straight, he _says_ that he wants to show $Tf$ is continuous, not $T$...